# Durandal delayed composition on landing page?

Tags: durandal

I've been using Durandal for a landing page of sorts, and using it to populate the main content of a page (`#applicationHost`, red area below).  It works, but page rendering speed is an issue (requirejs, ajax calls, composition, etc)

Since we have the content data already, we were considering rendering the page content server-side.

However we would still like to use Durandal on this page to allow hash-routing to other views, trigger Durandal dialogs, and to data-bind some observables that can be loaded asynchronously.  (areas in green below)

[image: Layout]

Problem is I don't want to replace #applicationHost content (red above) immediately when starting Durandal on this landing page.  For hash-routing to other views, I would like to replace or hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a decent solution for this, hope it helps others:

https://github.com/bestguy/durandal-delayed-composition

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like this might solve at least part of the problem.

You can use 'promises' to enforce a minimum delay between the splash screen loading and your app doing whatever startup it needs to do.  Assuming a common setup where your Durandal main.js loads shell.js on startup, return a combined promise from the shell.js 'activate' callback. I recommend using the Q library for promises ([Q + Durandal docs)](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Q/).

shell.js would contain something like the following.  The logic below causes the splash screen to be displayed for at least 3 seconds. Longer if initializeAppPromise takes longer than 3 seconds:

```
in shell.js...

activate = function(){

    var initializeAppPromise = router.map(....)..etc...activate();

    var minimumDelayPromise = Q.delay(3000); //give splash animation/whatever time to display

    return Q.all([initializeAppPromise, minimumDelayPromise ])
            .spread(function(routerActivationResponse){
                 return routerActivationResponse;
             });
    }
```